# Kendo date-range popup does not get close when I select start date and end date. (Angular 9)

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to use the Kendo date-range, but date-range popup does not get close when I select the start date and end date. Also, how can I  close when I select the start date and end date the same?

Ref. Link:
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/daterange/